# Inherit from own Control in Windows App

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, inheritance, controls

Im developing a Windows 8 App using WCF. For that i created my own control. Now i need another Control inherting from the first one. Is that basically possible?

In my try I created the first control using a VS tempalte which by default consists of a .cs and a .xaml file. The second one is a regular plain class which just inherits from the first one. But as soon as that second control gets initialized the App crashes with error message "Parser internal error: Object writer 'xClassNotDerivedFromElement'. [Line: 2 Position: 13]"

First control .cs:

```
namespace Reaction
{
    public partial class ReactionGame : UserControl
    {
        public bool finished = false;
        public bool winable = false;

        public ReactionGame()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public virtual void load()
        {
            // do all games actions (set up timers, etc)
        }

        public virtual void won()
        { 
            // called when the game is won (free grafics, animate win stuff)
        }

        public virtual void lost()
        {
            // called when the game is lost (free grafics, animate loose stuff)
        }
    }
}
```

First Control XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Reaction.ReactionGame"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Reaction"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid/>
</UserControl>
```

Second Control .cs (only):

```
namespace Reaction.ReactionGames
{
    public class WhiteGame:ReactionGame
    {

        Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer timer = null;

        public WhiteGame()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void load()
        {
            Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 5);
            timer.Start(); 
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            timer.Stop();

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Height = 200;
            rect.Width = 200;
            rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 105, 203, 44));
            this.Content = rect;

            winable = true;
        }

        public override void won()
        {
            MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Gewonnen!");
            msg.ShowAsync();
        }

        public override void lost()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code (and XAML, if any)

Comment: You're doing it all wrong. First of all, you cannot define an element in XAML if a base class of that element is defined in XAML. second, you shouldn't be manipulating UI elements in code. Third, a `UserControl` is not the right place for `public void won()` and `public void lost()`. I will post an example of the `right` way to do this in a couple of minutes.